# AngularJS 1 - Creating a Matrix with expandable headers and columns

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, matrix

I want to create a matrix (in AngularJS, not Angular2)
kind of table like so (code for this table below):

[image: example matrix]

However, I have one rather strange requirement. Both the top row and the first column need to be expandable. This means the (row)number "1" will unfold into more items, for example, "10, 100, 1000". These new numbers should be added either "under" 1 (see next image) or between 1 and 2.

The same applies to (column)number 1, this number should also be able to expand into the same "10,100,1000" and should be added (vertically) either "under" 1 or between 1 and 2.

Take a look at the following pictures as reference:

[image]

The following picture has been made using a table structure:

[image]

You can clearly see that "Europe" expanded into "Italy" and "Spain" and that Italy has expanded ever further into Rome and Milan.
The JSON used to create this is as follows:

```
 $scope.tasks = [
    {
        name: 'Europe',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'Italy',
                children: [
                    {
                        name: 'Rome'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Milan'
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                name: 'Spain'
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        name: 'South America',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'Brasil'
            },
            {
                name: 'Peru'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

The same JSON should be used for the side, effectively creating a matrix in which every match between all expanded items will be visible.

I have tried to create the matrix using tables and divs which behave as tables. Neither worked well for me. (with tables I ran into [this problem](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7295) and the divs problem is visible in the code).

Right now I'm at a loss, I have searched around for available products, of which there seem to be none, and I've tried doing it myself and I've concluded I need some help :)

For convenience sake, I've uploaded my test code to [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/mastermindzh/angularjs-matrix/src).

<sub>**Also, if I get a workable solution I will wait for the bounty to become available before I accept an answer.**</sub>

Comment: Currently looking at: https://github.com/TesserisPro/tgrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I built my own solution because the online solutions just weren't complete enough.

The one that came closest, and deserves a mention, is [Khan4019/tree-grid-directive](https://github.com/khan4019/tree-grid-directive) however.

Answer (score -1):

When creating complex table logic, regular `ng-repeat`'s may often not work, because it needs to be done *outside* of the `<tr>`'s, `<td>`'s and `<th>`'s.

The Angular team once proposed a way to add Angular code to HTML comments, such as directives and repeats, but apperantly [there were too many browser issues](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1646#issuecomment-21039443).

However, you can take a look at `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`, this solves (can solve) many problems related to tables and `ng-repeat`. At least, it did for me, and never ran into table issues ever since.

[Official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points)

And maybe [this blog post](https://www.undefinednull.com/2015/04/10/repeating-multiple-elements-using-ng-repeat-start-and-ng-repeat-end-in-angularjs/) will help you.

<sub><sub>Also, groetjes uit Hoorn</sub></sub>